# Android App Compatibility issue

Tags: android, hardware, compatibility

I have uploaded an app over android store some days ago, it's showing as not supported for galaxy s4 and Nexus 7 (i have just tested with those devices there could be more).

Here's the app URL

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lingapps.appwriter

I was looking around about the tablet permissions and found about the

Here's what permissions i am using right now.

> manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       package="com.lingapps.appwriter"
>       android:installLocation="auto"
>       android:versionCode="3"
>       android:versionName="1.0" >
>
> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="8"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
>
> <supports-screens
>     android:smallScreens="false" 
>     android:normalScreens="true"
>     android:largeScreens="true"
>     android:xlargeScreens="true"
>     android:anyDensity="true" />
>
> <compatible-screens>
>  <!--no small size screens -->
>
>
>  <!--all normal size screens -->
>  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
>
>  <!-- all large size screens -->
>  <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
>
>  <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
>  <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
>  <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
>
>  <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
>  <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />    </compatible-screens>
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
> <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
> <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
> ```

But why it's not showing compatible for the Galaxy s4, Any help would be very appreciating.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the   **android:targetSdkVersion="14"** to   **android:targetSdkVersion="17"**

Comment: otherwise u can do one thing just remove  android:targetSdkVersion="14"from code

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy s4 has **xxhdpi** resolution. You can see the phone specifications :). You need to add for xxhdpi as well. Google is supporting it.

This link will help you in understanding more:

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.kr/2013/03/how-to-develop-android-application-for.html

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

1) Remove the `<supports-screens>` block.

2) Target SDK level 19 (install this with SDK Manager if it is not already installed)

3) Add the following line to the `<comatible-screens>` block:

```
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
```